# Process for verifying X509 Certificate V3

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate

I'm required to create a program that validate any given X509 Certificate Version3 if it is trusted or not by verifying the signature. In order to to do that, I need to be able to know the issuer's public key who has signed that given certificate. I know how to output the issuer information using *getIssuerDN()* method but what I don't know is **how to get the issuer's public key when I only know its name**  !

**The only solution I have so far is to maintain a list of public keys for the most common Certificate Authorities on the web, and just search through it. Although this solution is doable, it seems impractical to me.**

Therefore, is there another idea to get the Issuer's public key from a certificate directly and then complete the process of verification ?

Here is my code for getting the Issuer's name but NOT its public key.

```
    URL url = new URL("https link here!");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.connect();

Certificate cert[] = con.getServerCertificates();
    X509Certificate x509cert = (X509Certificate) cert[0];
    String[] st= x509cert.getIssuerDN().toString().split(",");
    System.out.println("Issuer CN is: "+st[0].toString());
```

Comment: Think a moment about it. How secure would it be to extract the public key directly from the certificate you want to check with exactly that public key?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm required to create a program that validate any given X509 Certificate Version3 if it is trusted or not by verifying the signature. In order to to do that, I need to be able to know the issuer's public key who has signed that given certificate.

No. Either you or whoever gave you the assignment doesn't understand PKI. The idea is that you *already* trust some issuers by virtue of *already having* their certificates, e.g. in the cacerts file distributed with the JRE, and therefore their public keys. If the certificate you're asked to verify is traceable to one of these issuers *and* it passes all other verifications, you can trust it. Mere verification via the public key alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Do you mean that I can use carets file  when I want to verify a user certificate's signature ?